# How do I find a vector equation for the plane V that is described by an equation

Tags: vector-spaces

This is my first time working on 3 dimensional vectors and it went fine until I had to do the following:

Given is the plane $V$ described by the equation $$-56x +7y+11z=-1.$$

And I have to find a vector equation for plane $V.$

I know that you will need two direction vectors and a normal vector. But I don't really know where to start. Could someone give me a push in the right direction?

My calculation by working with three points:
[My calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlU0g.jpg)

Would this be correct?

Comment: Using the equation given, plug in different values of $x,y,z$ to get three points on the plane that are not collinear. Once you have the three points, you have one point and use the other two to get two vectors. Or check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772307/finding-vector-equation-of-a-plane-from-its-cartesian-equation

Comment: No, you need two direction vectors and a point on the plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Vector equation for plane $V$” is ambiguous, but from other parts of your question I gather that you want to find a parameterization of the form $\vec p+s\vec u+t\vec v$. For this you need two *linearly independent* vectors $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ that are parallel to $V$ and a point $\vec p$ on the plane.

You can rewrite the equation that you have in the form $\vec n\cdot\vec x=d$, specifically, $(-56,7,11)\cdot(x,y,z)=-1$. The fixed vector $\vec n=(-56,7,11)$ is perpendicular to the plane—*normal* to it. Now, for any nonzero vector $(a,b,c)$, the vectors $(0,-c,b)$, $(c,0,-a)$ and $(-b,a,0)$ are all orthogonal to it, and at least two of them are nonzero and linearly independent (verify this!). So, you can find suitable vectors $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ from $\vec n$ with basically no work. The only other thing you need is a point on the plane, and you can find one easily by setting two of the variables in the equation to zero and solving for the remaining one.

Answer (score 0):

Thre are several ways to write the vector Eq. for the plane, the simplest one is:
$$\vec n . \vec r=-1, ~\vec n=-56 \vec i+ 7 \vec j + 11 \vec k.$$